# Poisson Distribution, First chance of occuring on certain day?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

I have a Poisson distribution with λ = 10, which is the responses over 5 business days (Monday - Friday inclusive), with the probability constant through the week.

What would be the probability the first response comes on Tuesday? I am thinking since all events are independent and the probability is constant on every day, it would just be Poisson distribution of P(X=1).

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please explain your notation. The Poisson distribution only has a single parameter, but you're specifying two. Also, please see [this tutotiral and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) on how to typeset math on this site.

Comment: Do you mean the number of responses each day is distributed like a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes, the number of responses in a week (5 business days) is distributed like a Poisson distribution. λ = 10.

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't understand your notation. What do you mean by "it would just be Poisson distribution of $P(X=1)$"? Please introduce any variables you use. What is $X$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If I understand correctly, I would say that

X ~ number of events per business day (integer random variable $\ge 0$, Poisson distribution with the parameter $\lambda_1=\lambda/5$).

Then

- P(X=0) = the probability no event on Monday,
- P(X>=1) = the probability on Tuesday at least one event.

This must be true at one stroke.